# Generate nested JSON (reverse lateral flatten)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I use Snowflake to generate nested JSON from table data?

We can use the dot notification to specify where in a JSON file to read data from, is it possible to the reverse and specify a hierarchy to save data?

My end goal is to output a dataset without duplicating parent values, but nesting children underneath instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object_construct function would be of help here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html

A couple of related how-to articles:

1. https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Generating-a-JSON-Dataset-using-Relational-Data-in-Snowflake
2. https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Merge-Combine-Two-JSON-Fields